Mirror on Hook modifier
I'm a beginner at blender so I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this perfectly.

This is my model and I'm trying to animate it.
The idea is to have the two armes stretching and squashing the cube in the middle.
I can move the top arm while moving the bottom one using mirror modifier.
I added an Empty named FullBodyHook to control it.
I managed to have the top on working using the hook modifier on the to face of the cube linked to FullBodyHook.

Now I want the bottom face of the cube to move in a mirror manner to the top while it still being perfectly symetrical. (I don't want to have to animate the bottom manualy)
I created an Empty hooked to the bottom but no matter what I was trying I couln't have it mirror the action of FullBodyHook.
Is there a way to do that in Blender.
Thank you for your help

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Wanting the actions of one object to control of another? Think drivers.

Right click the value you want to use to "drive" the value of another. Lets go with the Z-axis location for this example.

Then paste the value into whatever value you want to be controlled with right click as well.

By itself this driver will just copy the values from one to the other, but if you change it to "Scripted Expression" and set the driver to be "location * -1" it will invert that value.

End result:

I set the X-axis location to be copied 1:1 and the Z-axis to be the inversion of the controller object.

Thank you for your help !

Did this answer solve your problem @AntoineBedry?

It did thank you

Cool, then can you accept the answer so that it removes the Q from the unanswered questions queue?
